# Cloning a repo keeps asking for password

Tags: git, github, ssh

I've been given the task to clone a repository that is located at `git@xx.xx.xxx.xxx:project.git`.  I've got the VPS IP address, VPS password and public key `myrepo.pub` so i can access the repository.  This is all the information i have and have been told is all i need.

I've downloaded GitHub for windows and put the public key `myrepo.pub` into the `.ssh` folder.  I've created a config file in the `.ssh` folder which looks like below.

```
host git@xx.xx.xxx.xx
 HostName git@xx.xxx.xxx.xx
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/myrepo.pub
 User root
```

Now when i open GIT and attempt to clone `git clone git@xx.xxx.xxx.xx:project.git`, i get asked for a password.  I've been told:

*"If everything is set right - no authorization (password) will be required as server authorizes you with your public key. This public key is your marker."*

How do i solve this?  Is it my config file? This is my first time using GIT, any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please consider accepting my answer if it solved your problem. Otherwise, you may comment on it saying why it wasn't helpful so that I can improve it.

Comment: Sorry, i've just got back to my computer.  I'm implementing now,will let you know if it works.

Answer (score 4):

You actually need your *private* key in your local `.ssh` folder. The *public* key goes in the server's `.ssh/authorized_keys`. The idea is that in order to authorize yourself you absolutely **need** your private key, but the people/servers/programs you authorize *to* need only your public key.

Also, your configuration is somewhat confusing. You may want something like:

```
Host myserver
    User git
    HostName xx.xxx.xxx.xx
    PubkeyAuthentication yes
    PreferredAuthentications publickey
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/myrepo
```

Then you can clone the repository with `git clone myserver:project.git <target_directory>`. If `<target_directory>` isn't provided by either a relative or an absolute path, **git** usually tries to clone into `./project/`. It may give you errors if the folder already exists and is not empty.

Whether you need to enter a password depends only on whether you set your private key with such or not.

A few notes on the configuration:

- The `git@` part of the address is the user *on the server* which you need to enter here.
- The two additional lines may not be necessary, but it's good practice to include them.
- You can read the appropriate ***man*** page for more information on
  all possible options in this file: `man ssh_config`.

Comment: Thanks, is `myserver` the  ip address of the vps?

Comment: I try to clone with GIT Bash and i get `fatal: destination path 'myrepo' already exists and is not an empty directory.`  I tried with GIT Shell and i still get asked for a password?

Comment: When i type `~/.ssh/config/` This is returned  `/c/Users/Dave/.ssh/config: line 1: Host: command not found
/c/Users/Dave/.ssh/config: line 2: User: command not found
HostName: cannot set hostname; this system lacks the functionality
/c/Users/MDave/.ssh/config: line 4: PubkeyAuthentication: command not found
/c/Users/Dave/.ssh/config: line 5: PreferredAuthentications: command n                                               ot found
/c/Users/Dave/.ssh/config: line 6: IdentityFile: command not found`

Comment: Not necessarily, `myserver` is just an alias of your choice. The IP address (or the hostname) is `xx.xxx.xxx.xx` as per your definition above.

You can give a custom directory to clone into with `git clone myserver:project.git my_custom_directory_to_clone_into`. By default it should actually be called `project` if you don't provide anything after the remote address, so your error message doesn't make any sense like that.

In any case, you can't clone a git repository into a non-empty local directory, so you should either delete it, or provide an explicit one (see above).

Comment: `~/.ssh/cofig` is a normal UNIX-type text file, so a trailing slash doesn't do anything good. In fact, you shouldn't have to "call it" as it is automatically assumed by the SSH process. What kind of system are you using?

Comment: I'm using windows 7.  Just to be clear, another developer in France has set this up and he sent me the public key to clone his repository, so i can work on the front end.    I had no idea GIT is this confusing.  I'll try again after reading your suggestions.  Thanks, you've been a great help.

Comment: I tried again, i renamed `myserver` to `expenses_app` and put this in GIT Bash `$ git clone expenses_app:expenses.git` and now i get this error `Cloning into 'project' ...  Enter passphrase for key 'c/Users/Zoostrom/.ssh/myrepo.pub';  Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyez,gssapi-with-mic,password). fatal:Could not read from remote repository`  What did i do wrong?

Comment: As already said, `git clone expenses_app:expenses.git` should try to clone into `'expenses'`; `git clone expenses_app:expenses.git project` should try to clone into `'project'`. However, your problem seems to be with the authentication since you have only the public key (if I understood correctly) and this is not enough. You can think of the *public* key as a *lock* and the *private* key as a *key* for that lock. You can distribute the lock (the public key) on arbitrary remote servers (e.g. where the actual repository is) and use your key (the private key) in order to "open" it.

Comment: So someone else giving you their public key is the wrong workflow. You need to first **generate** a new key. On UNIX-type operating systems (like Linux or Mac OS), you can do it with `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "your_email@example.com"` (substitute with your real e-mail address; not sure how and where you can call this on Windows). Then move the private key (e.g. `myrepo`) to the `.ssh` folder (if not already there) and send the *public* key (`myrepo.pub`) to the server administrator. They should know where to put it *on the server*.

Comment: I've already generated a private key into the .ssh folder.  I can connect to the vps by using `$ ssh git@xx.xx.xxx.xx`  and i successfully put in password.  It says `Last login: Wed Dec  2 17:59:12 2015 from xx.xx.xxx.xx`  Then is says `git@xxxxxx [~]#
` and i attempt to clone by using `git clone git@xx.xx.xxx.xx:expenses.git` and i get this error again `fatal: destination path 'expenses' already exists and is not an empty directory`.  It should clone into the `expenses` folder not on the server but on my computer, right?

Comment: I have an empty `expenses` repository on my desktop and the repository on the server contents should copy into there.

Comment: Yes, you got that right. However, the error message is self-explanatory. The local `expenses` folder cannot already exist and be non-empty in order to clone into it. It shouldn't be an *empty repository*, but a completely empty folder, or even non-existant one since **git** will create it. After cloning you will have the respective repository in that folder.

If it is an already-existing *empty repository*, you can set the **default remote** with `git remote add origin git@xx.xx.xxx.xx:expenses.git` and then directly `pull` and `push` from and towards it.